# Adding an FSL flow based quick Action on FSL Mobile App

Tags: visual-workflow, quickaction, lightning-flow-builder, fsl, work-order

I have quick action on Work Order Object. This quick action is a type of Field Service Mobile Flow - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mfs_flow_build.htm&type=5

[image]

I have added it to the correct page layout under Salesforce mobile and lightning experience actions.

[image]

When I log in as an FSL mobile user, I am unable to see that under "**Actions**". I made sure the page layout is correct and it has the quick action added.

[image]

I looked at this article but it does not talk about adding quick action flows - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mfs_quick_actions.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the mobile users did not have the Flow user settings checked on the user record OR run flow setting checked on the profile.

As soon as the user has the ability to run flow the quick action appeared under action.